# Springdoc GroupedOpenApi not following global parameters set with OperationCustomizer

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

When using `GroupedOpenApi` to define an API group, the common set of parameters that are added to every endpoint is not present in the parameters list.
Below are the respective codes

```java
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi v1Apis() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("v1 APIs")
            // hide all v2 APIs
            .pathsToExclude("/api/v2/**", "/v2/**")
            // show all v1 APIs
            .pathsToMatch("/api/v1/**", "/v1/**")
            .build();
}
```

And the class to add the Standard Headers to all the endpoints

```java
@Component
public class GlobalHeaderAdder implements OperationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        operation.addParametersItem(new Parameter().$ref("#/components/parameters/ClientID"));
        operation.addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("Authorization"));
        List<Parameter> parameterList = operation.getParameters();
        if (parameterList!=null && !parameterList.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.rotate(parameterList, 1);
        }
        return operation;
    }
}
```

Actual Output

[image: Actual Output]

Expected Output

[image: Expected Output]

**Workaround**

Adding the paths to be included/excluded in the application properties file solves the error. But something at the code level will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attach the required `OperationCustomizer`object while building the Api Group.

```java
@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi v1Apis(GlobalHeaderAdder globalHeaderAdder) {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("v1 APIs")
            // hide all v2 APIs
            .pathsToExclude("/api/v2/**", "/v2/**")
            // show all v1 APIs
            .pathsToMatch("/api/v1/**", "/v1/**")
            .addOperationCustomizer(globalHeaderAdded) 
            .build();
}
```

Edit: Answer updated with reference to [@Value not providing values from application properties Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840329/9269177)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to add and load OperationCustomizer in the case you declare yours open api groups by properties `springdoc.group-configs[0].group=` instead definition by Java code in a Spring Configuration `GroupedOpenApi.builder()`.

```
  @Bean
  public Map<String, GroupedOpenApi> configureGroupedsOpenApi(Map<String, GroupedOpenApi> groupedsOpenApi, OperationCustomizer operationCustomizer) {
    groupedsOpenApi.forEach((id, groupedOpenApi) -> groupedOpenApi.getOperationCustomizers()
                                                                  .add(operationCustomizer));
    return groupedsOpenApi;
  }
```